# Why do i can't to add library in maven?

Tags: java, maven

I use intellij IDEA 15.0.3 and it has a built-in version of maven. When I try to add a library (mysql-connector), maven can't seem to find it.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kBDj.png)

Comment: Code excerpts should never be included as images. Please edit your question.

Comment: Add more details about your setup. (settings.xml, intellij mvn options). Check local repository for your dependency.

Comment: Already tried to reload the maven dependencies using the "Maven Projects" view?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not tell Intellij to download dependencies automatically, it will continue showing like that on the picture. There are possible ways to follow. You can build your project with `mvn clean install` or you can change the settings of intellij to download artifacts automatically or you can triger download by clicking the button on the maven menu of the intellij.